# Sql query not working while using group by clause

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, group-by

I have written a query in `sql`, which contains `group by` clause.

The group by clause is used on an attribute which is neither primary key or unique key, I have read at various places that when we are using **mysql** it generally takes any arbitrary row, but in **postgreSql**, it doesn't behave in the same manner.
So I have used aggregation function while writing the query.

The query I have written is :

```
select user_id, min(priority) from table where is_active = 'false' group by user_id;
```

This query is working fine, but when I try to get information about any other attribute I am getting an error.

New Query:

```
select id,user_id, min(priority) from table where is_processed='false' group by user_id;
```

and the error is :

```
column "table.id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function.
```

Am I missing something ??

**Explanation:**

As per the answers suggests, I should use id or anything else that I need to select after group by clause.
But It will change the change the concept.
Say I have a table "Pending_Entries". It consists some attributes like id,userd_id,is_active and priority.
Now I need to find the `user_id and the minimum priority` corresponding to that `user_id`. For that I used the initial query and it is working perfectly fine. Now suppose I need the `id` too.

What should I do ?

Comment: As the error message implies, any column that is not an aggregation function must appear in the `GROUP BY` clause. If you want columns `id` and `user_id` you must repeat them in the `GROUP BY` clause.

Comment: With `group by user_id` you say you want one result row per `user_id`. So what `id` do you want to show in case there are different IDs for one `user_id` in the table? For `priority` you have decided to show the minimum priority per `user_id`. What is your decision for `id`?

Comment: @ThorstenKettner: Id is unique in this case

Comment: If `id` is unique for a `user_id` here, this suggests a strange table design (why do you have `id` at all, when `user_id` is already unique for the table?). On the other hand, then you can pick any ID, i.e. it doesn't matter if you take `min(id)` or `max(id)`. Use the one you like better :-)

Comment: @ThorstenKettner : I think you mis interpreted me. Id is unique for every tuple, but user_id is not unique

Comment: Ah, you are right, I neglected the `WHERE` clause part. I am sorry for my remark concerning your table design. I was wrong. So `id` is unique for `user_id` plus `is_processed=false`. But still, use `min(id)` or `max(id)` to get the id. However, the answers given should also work, because adding `id` to your `GROUP BY` clause shouldn't change anything, because it is already unique in the group.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner : Yaa, you are correct, conceptually it should not change but by running queries it is not giving desired results.

Comment: Then your assumptions must be incorrect. Pick a user_id from your results that doesn't match your expectations. Then select the data for that user_id only, but without aggregation. Then look at the records you get, especially the `id` which you assume to be the same in all records. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is normal; MySQL is not correct.  In Postgres, you can use `distinct on`:

```
select distinct on (user_id) t.*
from table t
where is_processed = 'false'
order by user_id, prioirty asc;
```

In MySQL, your query works syntactically, but it is not doing what you want.  It is returning an arbitrary value for the columns not in the `group by` and not in aggregation functions.

There are many ways to have a query work in both systems:

```
select t.*
from table t
where t.is_processed = 'false' and
      t.priority = (select min(t2.priority)
                    form table t2
                    where t2.user_id = t.user_id and t2.is_processed = 'false'
                   );
```

Comment: This is working fine, but I don't want to use nested queries

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
select id,user_id, min(priority) from table where is_processed='false' group by user_id, id, priority;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is evident from your error message, isn't it?

Include the column in your [GROUP BY](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp)

```
select id,user_id, min(priority) from table where is_processed='false' group by id,user_id,priority;
```

Answer (score 0):

Add column 'id' after 'group by'

```
select id,user_id, min(priority) from table where is_processed='false' group by user_id, id;
```